# Book series about a family surviving a zombies epidemic while living on a sailboat around the Bahamas

Tags: story-identification, zombie

I need a book ID. Some time ago I read 3 or 4 books about a family surviving a zombies epidemic while living on a sailboat around the Bahamas. From there they go about to save the world.

Comment: Can you recall any other details about this book? There might not be much to go on at the moment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sounds like the [***Black Tide Rising***](https://www.goodreads.com/series/110176-black-tide-rising) series by [**John Ringo**](https://www.fantasticfiction.com/r/john-ringo/).

The series consists of

- Under a Graveyard Sky #1
- To Sail a Darkling Sea #2
- Islands of Rage and Hope #3
- Strands of Sorrow #4
- Black Tide Rising (Short stories in the same universe with Ringo as editor)

> A family of survivors who fight back against a zombie plague that has brought down civilization.
>
> Zombies are real. And we made them. Are you prepared for the zombie apocalypse? The Smith family is, with the help of a few marines.
>
> When an airborne “zombie” plague is released, bringing civilization to a grinding halt, the Smith family, Steven, Stacey, Sophia and Faith, take to the **Atlantic** to avoid the chaos. The plan is to find a safe haven from the anarchy of infected humanity. What they discover, instead, is a sea composed of the tears of survivors and a passion for bringing hope.

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot